# How to redirect value to another controller inside CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-variables

I am currently trying to implement some functionality inside my CodeIgniter application:
Inside one controller I want to assign a value to a variable stored somewhere globally, so it can be read by another controller after the redirect.

- The problem here is that the value may change on the runtime (so it is not a constant value), that's why I cannot use config for storing that value. Furthermore, config file will reset to its defaults when redirecting from one controller to another.
- Post or get methods cannot be used as well.
- The value is too sensitive to store it using sessions.

I have tried to create a singleton (a class extending CI_Model in this example). Setting the singleton's value from one controller is working, but reading this value from another controller is not. The model is autoloaded, so it is accessible by every controller in the application. Also extending the CI_Controller class does not resolve my problem. Have you any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: One way I would suggest is to store in a session but encrypt the data before storing it in the session. Other than that (with Standard CI) I really don't think it can be done. Also, when you say it can be read by another controller, I assume you mean after a redirect?

Comment: You have lots of restriction.You can use it two ways.Use database table or write the value inside a file.

Comment: @RossWilson Yes, I mean after a redirect.

Comment: In that case I would have to agree with @ShaifulIslam , DB is probably going to be the best way you can do this...plus you don't have to worry about session expiration either.

Comment: What I actually wanted is a situation where someone can connect to a MySQL database by typing database username and database password into a form. Something like phpmyadmin.

Comment: declare it on a helper file (may you must create one) load this helper in every controller you want to use or globally in yuor autoload https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html